# Workingset/privateWorkingSet memory don't add up to memory usage in Task manager

Tags: windows, memory-management, process, operating-system, taskmanager

**Memory Issue**

One of our server boxes shows 96% memory usage in task manager (137/140GB or so used).

When I look in the "Processes" tab though (even with show processes from all users checked), the top processes combined only use 40GB or so combined at peak times.  I've provided an image of top used processes below as well as an image of the performance panel showing the memory usage.

*Note: CPU usage isn't usually at 99%, it spiked when I took that screenshot.*

**My Question**

What is the reason for this discrepancy, and how can I more accurately tell which processes are eating the other 100GB of memory?

---

[image: Task manager top memory usage processes]

To verify, here's an image of the performance pannel:

[image: Performance Pannel]

Comment: RamMap reveals where this “Missing Memory” may be hiding http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/12/19/where-has-all-my-physical-ram-gone.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergmat is correct in his comment (thanks by the way); I actually found RAMMAP myself yesterday and used it and it revealed the problem.

Our server runs a very heavily used SQL Server instance.  RAMMAP reveals that there is a 105GB region of memory used for "AWE" Address Windowing Extensions - which are used to manipulate large regions of memory very quickly by things like RDBMS's (SQL Server).

Apparently you can configure the maximum memory SQL Server would use, this being included; so that's the solution.